# Hide / Show Navbar ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navbar, router, nav

I have a problem when trying to hide the navbar on my login page but i don't know how to do this.

You can see my code here:

```
    render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <div >
          <Nav />
          <button type="button" className="form-submit_logout" onClick= 
{this.handleLogout.bind(this)}>Logout</button>

          <Route path="/" exact component={Login}/>
          <Route path="/ChooseRole" exact component={ChooseRole}/>

          <Route path="/DashboardGeek" exact component= . 
{DashboardGeek}/>
          <Route path="/DashboardAdmin" exact component= . 
{DashboardAdmin}/>
          </div>
      </Router>
```

Please help me solve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have the  component at root level, so it'd render in all pages.

Try including it as child to  `ChooseRole`, `DashboardGeek` and `DashboardAdmin` components individually. That should solve the problem.

Comment: You must have separate files created/classes defined representing `ChooseRole`, `DashboardGeek` and `DashboardAdmin`. Inside their render method, just include  `<Nav />`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways around this, it depends on the scale of your application but IMO the simplest is below.

I would assume you are using a boolean or a user object in your App or global state? Try adding a boolean to render the Nav like: `{this.state.loggedIn ? <Nav /> : ''}`

You can also generate an 'AppTemplate' component that passes the routes as `props.children` or includes it in every page.